# copy an existing meta_value to a new meta_key name - WordPress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am trying to copy a meta_key and the corresponding meta_value to a new row in the `wp_postmeta` table where the meta_key gets a new name but with the original `meta_value`.

I can copy one post with MySQL but this needs to be done for more than 300 posts so there must be a way to do this in a statement.

Example given:
meta_key: postalCode
meta_value: 1234AA 
needs to be copied to for the corresponding post id to
meta_key: wpcf-adres
meta_value:1234AA

I have tried:
update wp_postmeta  set meta_key = 'postalCode'  where meta_key = 'wpcf-adres'

but this, of course, does not duplicate and keep the original meta_key but just renames it.

I hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

Thanks a lot for looking into it.

Kind regards

Wim

```php
update wp_postmeta  set meta_key = 'postalCode'  where meta_key = 'wpcf-adres'
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't my code, I saved it previously but it may be what you're after. Switching the keys as needed.

```
 <?php
 // HOOK ON REGISTERING NEW USER/CUSTOMER
 add_action('user_register', 'mm_sync_phone_number' , 20, 1);    
 // HOOK ON PERSONAL OPTIONS UPDATE
 add_action('personal_options_update', 'mm_sync_phone_number' , 20, 1);
 // HOOK ON USER PROFILE UPDATE    
 add_action('edit_user_profile_update','mm_sync_phone_number' , 20, 1); 
 function mm_sync_phone_number( $user_id ) { 
 // GET PHONE NUMBER FROM OTHER FIELD
     $phone_number = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'meta_key_of_other_phone_field', true );
 // UPDATE PHONE NUMBER IN BILLING PHONE NUMBER FIELD
 update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone',  $phone_number ); 
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, i have just tried to adjust the code to code below but this does not seem to do anything so I quess  i am still missing something?

`function sync_postalcode( $post_id ) {

 // GET Postal code FROM OTHER FIELD
     $postcode = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'postalCode', true);
 // UPDATE Postalcode IN adres FIELD
 update_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpcf-adres', $postcode );
 }

add_action( 'save_post', 'sync_postalcode' );`